# Quantity change after page change in Views with ajax

Tags: 7, views, commerce, ajax

I'm showing products using Views and there is Ajax enabled, so I have ajax pager. Add to cart form with quantity is added in View as Product Reference field.

Everything is ok until I change page, after that + and - button doesn't work, but add to cart button working as usual.

I'm using [Commerce Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra) module in order to get + and - for quantity field.

Does someone had any experience with this or maybe idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Just try enabling or disabling  Use AJAX in view setting

Comment: Yes, of course, if I disable Ajax then everything working ok, but I need that Ajax functionality in Views because I need exposed filters and pager to work through Ajax...